# Javascript solution to print specified area. Cross-browser friendly

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, printing, cross-browser

I am currently developing a site which requires a print option on the page. When clicked this button fires a script that prints all contents within a `<span id='printArea'></span>`.

I am using a jQuery plugin called printElement at the moment and it works very well in all browsers that I have tested except Google Chrome.

I have researched this problem and applied a suggested solution involving a setTimeOut() but have had no luck.

My question is: can anyone suggest a good cross-browser solution for printing a defined area of a web page?

Comment: What isn't working in Chrome? I haven't had issues here.

Comment: When I click print, the popup window shows but it is blank. You can try it out yourself if you like: http://1641.kco.ie/deposition.php?depID=834004r004 

You will need to login: test@kco.ie - t3stP@$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you not just [create a printable styleshee](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/printyourway/)t, which hides all the other areas of the page that you don't want printing?

Comment: I suspect it may be that there's some dynamic aspect to this. For example, perhaps user interaction selects some part of a page (a single catalog item, or something like that), and then the user is given an option to print that chosen thing.

Comment: In this case you could just generate a page which just contained the selected items, attach a print stylesheet and trigger the system print dialog.

Answer (score 2):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/print.css" media="print" />
```

print.css

```
@charset "utf-8";
nav, header, #status-bar, #sub-nav, #header-shadow, footer, #tips{
    display:none !important;
}
```

Comment: In the future, please add a description to your post and not just code.  :)